# What process signal does pod receive when executing `kubectl rolling-update`?

Tags: docker, signals, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am making graceful shutdown feature using go lang when kebernetes doing rolling-update on google container engine. Does anyone know what process signal is sent to the running pods when kubectl rolling-update starts?

I've listened to os.Kill, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGKILL, syscall.SIGSTOP signals to be handled, none of those signals was raised while kubectl rolling-update.

I would really appreciate for your answers.

Comment: first show us what have you tried? What do you mean by "no-one was effective "?

Comment: Hi Pawan. Sorry for making you confused. I meant Kill, Interrupt, SIGTERM, SIGKILL, SIGSTOP were not raised in my process.

Answer (score 2):

I got a solution! I used shell script file as an ENTRYPOINT and executed go binary in that script file. So process ID of executed go binary was not 1.(shell script process's ID was 1 instead) And docker sent SIGTERM only to PID 1(which is not propagated to it's child processes). So, I had to change my ENTRYPOINT direct to executing go binary, and I got SIGTERM in my go code now. Refer to this [link](https://labs.ctl.io/gracefully-stopping-docker-containers/)